# Stored procedure input validation in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-injection

I have imported a SQL Server stored procedure into the `.edmx` file. I'm calling the generated method like:

```
entity.MySP(stringInput)
```

Does the `stringInput` parameter need to be validated (for SQL injections etc) when using EF, or can I assume EF does that for me? If not, is there a method I can call to escape/validate the input parameter?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, .NET 4.0, C#, ASP.NET MVC 4, VS2010.

EDIT:
Note that I'd like to use LINQ instead of calling a SP, but I'm using FREETEXT, so I *think* this is the more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about LINQ to Entity Framework Security here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx.  Look at the section titled "Security Considerations for Queries".

To answer your question specifically, Entity Framework will call your stored procedure and pass in the stringInput value.  That means even if stringInput is a SQL statement meant to inject something harmful into your database, just passing it to your stored procedure will not cause a SQL Injection attack.

However, depending on how you use stringInput in your stored procedure, you could still leave yourself open to an attack.  Specifically, if you use stringInput in a dynamic SQL statement that you execute, you are leaving yourself open to attack.  If you use it to do a compare in the WHERE section of a SELECT statement you should be safe.

Comment: I'm putting it directly into the FREETEXT and CONTAINS functions. I assume, I'm safe?

Comment: Yes, that will not cause an issue. The command sp_executesql is the big one that can allow for SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are doing inside of your stored proc. Simply by using stored procs, you are not immune to SQL Injection. Conversely, by using variables in your LINQ to Entity code, you are safe from SQL Injection because the query is parameterized correctly there as well. Unfortunately, full text indexing is not supported in Entity Framework, so you will need to resort to procs or functions to use them for performance concerns. I wouldn't say that it is necessarily more "elegant" than a LINQ generated query however.